# I set my pushbutton switch up incorrectly

Tags: arduino

I am fiddling with an Arduino Uno and trying to get two switches to operate two servo motors. I am not able to do this right now, and I am not sure what my issue is. I know that my servos are wired correctly; however, I highly doubt that my switches are correctly wired.

Here is a diagram of my circuit and the code that I am using.

```
    #include <Servo.h>

    Servo servo_11;

    Servo servo_10;

    void setup()
    {
      servo_11.attach(11);

      servo_10.attach(10);

      pinMode(A3, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(A2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(A2, INPUT);
    }

    void loop()
    {
      servo_11.write(0);
      servo_10.write(0);
      digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
      if (analogRead(A2) != LOW) {
        servo_11.write(180);
      }
      delay(10); 
    }
```

[Circuit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl4j3.png)
If anyone could point out what's wrong, I would really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

You have floating inputs.  When the button isn't pressed the pin isn't connected to anything.  So the pin can read whatever noise it happens to pick up from the environment.  You need pull-down or pull-up resistors.  If you use pull-ups, then you can use the ones built into the chip.

You also seem to be confusing analogRead and digitalRead.  It's digitalRead that gets HIGH and LOW.  analogRead gets values from 0 to 1023 for 0 to 5V.

Comment: There is a nice Arduino tutorial on pushbuttons at https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button If you copy that circuit and code, I'm sure you'll have success. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[pull-down resistor circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vihYD.png)

try looking on this to understand the concept
it makes sure that when you dont press the pin will read ground and only when it presses the button you make voltage divider that ups the volage to a non-zero to give you HIGH